# Problems with RGB and NSColor

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am using this code:

```
#define MAATTACHEDWINDOW_DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:59 green:89 blue:152 alpha:0.75]
```

And trying to obtain a background color using RGB but it's giving me the color white. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you have passed in are incorrect for what it expects; they have to be between 0 and 1. Anything above 1 is set to 1.0.

Comment: Just multiply your values by 1.0 and then divide by 255.

Comment: Completely forgot haha, too wrapped up in this project. Thanks for reminding me!